# Limit inferior of product of two non negative bounded sequences

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

I have two contradicting proofs for the property:
\begin{align}\liminf (a_nb_n)  \geq (\liminf (a_n)) * (\liminf (b_n))\end{align}
where ${a_n}$ and ${b_n}$ are two bounded non-negative sequences.

(Proof 1 is given in Book: Mathematical Analysis by SC Malik and Savita Arora Edition 5 Theorem 18; Proof 2 - I thought of it)

So, I was curious to know where the flaw is in the **Proof 2**

**Proof 1**: We note that if $\liminf a_n =0$ OR $\liminf b_n =0$, then the inequality follows immediately.
Therefore we assume that $\liminf a_n  =a>0$ and $\liminf b_n =b>0$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then as it is known, (for limit inferiors) there exists integers $m_1$ and $m_2$ respectively, such that
$$
a_n > a - (\frac{\epsilon}{2b}), \forall n\geq m_1 \\
b_n > b - (\frac{\epsilon}{2a}), \forall n\geq m_2
$$

Therefore, for all $n \geq \max(m_1, m_2)$, we have
\begin{align}
a_nb_n >(a -\frac{\epsilon}{2b})*(b-\frac{\epsilon}{2a})=ab-(\epsilon + \frac{\epsilon^2}{4ab})> ab - \epsilon
\end{align}This implies that, lim inf($a_nb_n) \geq ab - \epsilon$
But $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, hence the results follows:
\begin{align}\liminf (a_nb_n)  \geq (\liminf (a_n)) * (\liminf (b_n))\end{align}

**Proof 2**:
Since $a$ and $b$ are limit inferiors of $a_n$ and $b_n$ respectively the following holds,
\begin{align}
a_n < (a +\frac{\epsilon}{2b}) & \text{ for infinitely many values of n}\\
b_n < (b +\frac{\epsilon}{2a}) & \text{ for infinitely many values of n}
\end{align}Considering the following property of limit inferior:
\begin{align*}
\text{If } \alpha \in \mathbb{R }\text{ is such that \{ } {\text{n: } a_n < \alpha} \text{ is infinite \}, then lim inf  } a_n \leq \alpha.
\end{align*}From (1) and (2) above, we have
\begin{align*}
a_nb_n < ab + \epsilon + \frac{\epsilon^2}{4ab} & \text{ for infinitely many values of n}
\end{align*}Now since $\epsilon$ is taken arbitrarily, considering small $\epsilon$ and also applying above property, we see that:
\begin{align}\liminf (a_nb_n)  \leq (\liminf (a_n)) * (\liminf (b_n))\end{align}which is a contradiction to the proof mentioned in the first post.

Answer (score 1):

The second proof states that
\begin{align}
a_n < (a +\frac{\epsilon}{2b}) & \text{ for infinitely many values of $n$}\\
b_n < (b +\frac{\epsilon}{2a}) & \text{ for infinitely many values of $n$}
\end{align}
but that are not necessarily *the same* values of $n$ in both sequences. Therefore the conclusion
\begin{align*}
a_nb_n < ab + \epsilon + \frac{\epsilon^2}{4ab} & \text{ for infinitely many values of $n$}
\end{align*}
is wrong. As an example consider the sequences
$$
 a_n = 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, \ldots \\
 b_n = 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, \ldots
$$
If $\epsilon $ is sufficiently small then
\begin{align}
a_n < (a +\frac{\epsilon}{2b}) & \text{ for odd $n$}\\
b_n < (b +\frac{\epsilon}{2a}) & \text{ for even $n$}
\end{align}
so that there is no *common* subsequence where both estimates hold.